# How to convert a number to signed/unsigned 16/32 bits?

Tags: lua, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Okay, so I need to send signed/unsigned 16/32 bits integers using udp. How do I convert a Lua number to these types so I can write it byte by byte. I have access to bitwise operators.

I've searched this question thoroughly but I only found one function that didn't work with signed.

I couldn't even find any material explaining how to do this, so if someone could link me something, I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Just output them byte-for-byte.

Comment: Do you expect your Lua numbers to be in-range values for the types you want to pack in the udp message, or do you want to convert any Lua number to some sequence of smaller signed/unsigned 16/32 bits integers?

Comment: My Lua numbers will all be in range.

Answer (score 6):

If your Lua numbers are in the range of the type you are writing, then there is no conversion necessary. You just need to extract the bytes and write them.

Assuming big endian (network order), and Lua 5.3:

```
local b16H = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
local b16L = (x     ) & 0xff;
my_output(string.char(b16H, b16L));
```

This works for signed as well as unsigned.

For 32 bits

```
local b32HH = (x >> 24) & 0xff;
local b32HL = (x >> 16) & 0xff;
local b32LH = (x >>  8) & 0xff;
local b32LL = (x      ) & 0xff;
my_output(string.char(b32HH, b32HL, b32LH, b32LL));
```

Comment: How would I get the number back?

Comment: To get the number back use `string.byte` with `<<` and `|`.

Comment: @user3693079 The string data type in Lua is a counted sequence of bytes. That you could consider those bytes to represent text and there are some functions to help you do so isn't useful nor a hindrance in your case.

Comment: Doesn't this break when `x` is negative?

Comment: @avs, no, why do you think it will break? Note that the shifted bytes are all ANDed with `0xff` so no "shifted in" bits are used in the values that are output. While right shifting a signed value may invoke implementation defined behavior, this is only related to the "shifted in" bits, not the original value.

Comment: @DougCurrie I am limited to Lua 5.2 and was not able to convert your solution. Perhaps I made a mistake, you can see my attempt here: http://tpcg.io/.

Comment: @avs, the link doesn't work for me
This works in Lua 5.2.3:
    > function f(x)
    >>     local b32HH = bit32.band(bit32.rshift(x, 24), 0xff)
    >>     local b32HL = bit32.band(bit32.rshift(x, 16), 0xff)
    >>     local b32LH = bit32.band(bit32.rshift(x,  8), 0xff)
    >>     local b32LL = bit32.band(            (x    ), 0xff)
    >>     -- return string.char(b32HH, b32HL, b32LH, b32LL)
    >>     print(b32HH, b32HL, b32LH, b32LL)
    >> end
    > 
    > f(-1)
    255 255 255 255
    > f(99)
    0 0 0 99
    >